# Realm not query string field with whitespace

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have such function in my data source:

```
func getAllFood(by type: String) -> [UserFoodInformation] {
    var findedFood = [UserFoodInformation]()
    findedFood.append(contentsOf: baseUserFoodDataSource.getAllFood(by: type))
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "foodType == %@", type)
    let resultOfSearching = dataBase.objects(AddedUserFood.self).filter(predicate).sorted(byKeyPath: "name")
    for searchedFood in resultOfSearching {
        findedFood.append(searchedFood)
    }
    return findedFood
}
```

When I try to query with string that consist whitespace, I have no result, but if I query with simple one-word parameter, everything goes fine. Why is that? Can I have a string field in Realm that consists multiple words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicate you're using is looking for objects whose `foodType` property is equal to the `type` string that is passed in. Only those objects whose property is exactly equal to that string will match. If you want to perform some other form of matching you'll need to use something other than the equality operator. `BEGINSWITH`, `CONTAINS`, `ENDSWITH` and `LIKE` are the comparison operators that Realm supports on string fields.

> Can I have a string field in Realm that consists multiple words?

String fields can contain any string values. The supported comparison operators don't have the concept of a "word", though, so if you want to do filtering using that concept you'll likely need to do further work on your part. Depending on your use case, I can see a couple of ways to go about it:

- Use `CONTAINS` to find any objects whose `foodType` properties contains the given `type` string.
- Parse the string into structured data that you store in your model. For instance, it may make sense to store a `List<FoodType>` rather than a `String` for the `foodType` property.

There are likely other options, but they depend on details of what it is you're trying to achieve that you've not shared.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem was simpler: at some reason one moment my model return 0 results on filtering parameter that consist whitespace in himself, but after restore to my previous commit everything goes fine. Seems like it was my mistake at some part of searching.